# Query by Date in Java Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, date, spring-data-jpa

ETA: TL;DR:

orderRepo.save() converts the date (input):

```
Wed Jun 22 00:00:00 CDT 2022
```

into this (output):

```
2022-06-22 05:00:00.000
```

I am wondering how I can convert the input into the output, in Java, without putting it in the database first.

---

Original post:

I have a website that has been working with java.utils.Date for over a year now. I can use the angular date picker which makes an order object, sends it to java, repo.save() puts it in the database, pulls it back to angular and displays the date just fine.

I am now trying to query only a specific date from the DB.

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o JOIN o.boats b WHERE b.date = ?1")
    Set<Order> findByDate(Date date);
```

However this keeps turning up empty even though there are dates that match in the DB

How do I fix my query to grab those dates?

---

I know, "Don't use java.util.Date" but that is the system I am working with and I don't have time at the moment to convert everything to LocalDate. I will at some point but I am already quite behind on current tasks.

Thanks!!

Comment: Check your data.  Also, are your Spring application and database in the same time zone?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is why I am confused. The data and everything is the same as with all the other methods, but just doesn't work in this one case. The application and database should be in the same timezones because all of my other methods from moving the objects around keep the dates a the same time

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. For a date without time of day use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V.  I know I know, haha but that is the system I am working with and I don't have time at the moment to convert everything to LocalDate. I will at some point but I am already quite behind on current tasks. I also updated my post to more accurately express what I am currently looking for

Answer (score 0):

This method is a [jpql](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm)

I would have used another way.

Interface call method or [Query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

By calling a method request in the interface, we need our user interface to inherit the interface specified in the Spring Data Jpa:

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>
```

The prerequisite for using these methods is that the entity class you define should be marked with appropriate annotations.

```
@Entity //Mark this as an entity class
@Table(name = "tbl_user") //Setting the mapping relationship between the entity class and the public class User table {

@Id //Declare this attribute as the primary key
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) //Primary key generation strategy, self-reinforcing
@Column(name = "user_id") //The specified attribute corresponds to the column name of the database table
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "user_address")
private String userAddress;

@Column(name = "user_salary")
private Double userSalary;

//... setter method toString
}
```